# Acessing querystring and form parameters with Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

If you choose for whatever reason not to use modelbinding in a HttpPost request, what other ways are there to access the QueryString (HttpGet) or Form parameters (HttpPost)?

Traditionally you could do:

```
Request.QueryString["Key"]
Request.Form["Key"]
Request["Key"]
```

I can't seem to find anything similiar in Web API.

Answer (score 8):

For query string parameters you can use [`GetQueryNameValuePairs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.getquerynamevaluepairs(v=vs.118).aspx) on a `HttpRequestMessage` (it's an extension method).

For form data, you need to define the action as this and the raw form data (pre-parameter binding) will be passed to you:

```
public void Post(NameValueCollection formData)
{
   var value = formData["key"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

var queryString = request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
token = queryString["Authorization"];

Answer (score 0):

This is where Intellisense comes in handy. Just type `Request.` and see what you've got available to you. I've personally always just included parameters for my method for the data to bind to; not really sure what use case exists where you wouldn't just handle it that way. Nevertheless, from what I can see, there's `Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs` that will at least let you get at the query string. I can't see anything in `Request` that gives you access to the post body, but perhaps I missed it, or it's buried somewhere else other than `Request`.